# Why am I getting an IllegalComponentStateException?

Tags: java, swing, exception

```
java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Component.java:2062)
    at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:2036)
    at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent$InputMethodRequestsHandler.getTextLocation(JTextComponent.java:4643)
    at sun.awt.im.InputMethodContext.getTextLocation(InputMethodContext.java:278)
    at sun.awt.windows.WInputMethod$1.run(WInputMethod.java:588)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Why are you asking this question but not showing your pertinent code?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0):

Your getTextLocation call is causing the issue since the element you call it on is not visible when you do so.

Comment: Since `InputMethodContext` is in the `sun.awt.im` package, this I likely to be an internal API call, not one which is originating from the OP

Comment: Good catch, scratch what I have said